# Do we know specifically how the 4th Great Ninja War ended?

Tags: naruto

It says that it ended with Black Zetsu taking over Madara's body and Team 7 beating her, but I think it ended with Naruto and Sasuke's final battle:

[image]

Comment: "It says that" - *who* says that? Do you have a reason to believe your interpretation is more accurate than theirs?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Because by reading the manga and watching the anime, you will know how it ended. Or are you asking what events marked the end of this arc? If it's the latter, you can check here: https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Plot_of_Naruto

Comment: im asking what marked the end of the arc

Comment: Considering that the entire series ends just 10 chapters after the sealing takes place.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that depends on what you mean by "war".  Note: no spoilers since your picture implies a lot about how things went, and what the resolution was.

The Fourth Great Ninja War was a war against Madara to prevent him from capturing the Bijuu to activate the Infinite Tsukuyomi.

In that vein...the war was probably *lost* since the jutsu was actually successfully launched.

However, there's two ways to think about the actual resolution of the war - the perspective of those *impacted* in it, and the perspective of those *fighting* in it - and this would largely be Team 7.

**From the perspective of Team 7**, the war was concluded after the final fight between Naruto and Sasuke (which was *after* the fight with Kaguya), who then unified to release everyone else from the Infinite Tsukuyomi.

**From the perspective of those impacted, including the Allied Shinobi Forces**, the war was "simply over" by the time they were released from the Infinite Tsukuyomi.  Had Team 7 not continued fighting after Kaguya appeared, they would have officially lost, but would not have been able to ascertain that fact until they perished.